# Using both short term Access Token and long term acces tokenn

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using javasctip sdk and generating short term "User" access Token.I am using the flow as [described here](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t39.2178-6/851584_503291546407012_1005168000_n.png)

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

After generating the long term acces token(in server side) can I use the short term access token in my client side as it is much easier to use javascrip sdk than graph api

If not how can I tell facebook javascript sdk to use long term access token

Comment: you can still use th short term one, it will get used by the js sdk anyway. just try.